# Why publishing databricks notebook activity in azure synapse pipelines is giving error?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-synapse

I have a synapse pipeline which have multiple activities including a databricks notebook activity. I am able to validate and manually debug pipeline successfully but when I try to publish the pipeline it fails giving error that 'Databricks activity not supported'. Also I am able to publish pipeline when I remove databricks notebook activity. I have checked the databricks linked service also, it is created correctly and able to get a successful connection. I tried to publish similar pipeline including databricks notebook activity in ADF and it is publishing successfully in ADF. I want to publish pipeline in synapse analytics. I am attaching the screenshot of the error I am getting.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OALqf.png)

I tried removing databricks activity and it is publishing successfully. Also tried publishing the similar pipeline including databricks notebook activity in ADF and it is successfully publishing there also. But not able to publish in synapse analytics pipelines.

Attaching the json of notebook activity.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1ccS.png)

Comment: Can you provide Notebook activity configurations or activity JSON?

Comment: Is it giving the same result when you use the clone of that Notebook activity?

Comment: Hey @RakeshGovindula I have now attached the json of notebook activity in the question desciption . And even after cloning it gives the error. I tried creating a separate pipeline in synapse with only the clone of databricks notebook activity, but it gave the same issue.

Comment: I tried the same in my environment, but it is publishing without any errors for me. In your JSON, you did with Repo Notebook. Can you try and check whether it results the same with a normal databricks notebook from `Users`?

Comment: Tried using normal databricks notebook also, still no luck.

Comment: Facing the exact same error, this seems to be some kind of bug in Synapse Studio.
Does someone know how to raise it to Microsoft or is there any "known issues" tracker?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76667174/synapse-pipeline-databricks-activity-not-supported

the link https://github.com/Azure/Synapse/issues/16