# Synapse pipeline - Databricks Activity Not Supported

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-pipeline

I am facing the below error when a Synapse pipeline with Databricks notebook activity is used -

```
Error code: OK
Inner error code: BadRequest
Message: Databricks Activity Not Supported.
```

This seems to be a bug in the Synapse Studio as everything was running fine till yesterday.

If I run the pipeline manually in the debug mode it runs successfully, there are no validation errors as well.
This data bricks activity simply calls a notebook using a job cluster (by connecting to the instance pool) and runs some specific code.

Can someone please help? Or shall I raise it to Microsoft?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue raised for bug here. https://github.com/Azure/Synapse/issues/16

Comment: Ok, thank you! I will monitor this, in the meantime please let me know if you find any workaround.

Answer (score 1):

The databricks notebook activity Synapse pipeline publishing issue was temporary and has been resolved as of 2023-07-13 (at least within the Azure US South-Central region).

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in the Synapse studio and they have rolled back the deployment. As of west-Europe region, this issue is now resolved and I can publish a pipeline that has the Databricks notebook activity.

Reference MS forum link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1328684/synapse-pipeline-databricks-activity-not-supported?comment=answer-1285559&page=1#comment-1325743